# Lucene searches on 2 field values as single

Tags: lucene, lucene-highlighter

Lucene document has field `a` with content `hello` and `a` with content `world`. If i'll search `"hello world"~2` it will be founded =(. How can I fix it?
`FastVectorHighlighter` will highlight it like `<b>helloworld</b>` (without any space) (anyway it shouldn't highlight it)

Answer (score 0):

a seems to be an multivalued field.
Have you changed the positionincrementgap to a higher value ? The default value position increment gap is 0.
This will prevent the scenario.